# Python to pass value from a DataFrame to another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame as below. (index is Delivery Month with Columns 'Instruments' and 'Volume')

```
Delivery Month | Instruments| Volume
Oct-2020       |     A      |   5
Oct-2020       |     B      |   8
Nov-2020       |     B      |   12
Dec-2020       |     A      |   20
Dec-2020       |     C      |   8
Dec-2020       |     D      |   8
```

And I am trying to present the data in this table as below.(index is still month but removes the repeat ones and set up instruments as columns names + volume to the corresponding spots.)

```
           A  |  B  |  C  |  D  
Oct-2020   5  |  8  |     |
Nov-2020      | 12  |     |
Dec-2020   20 |     |  8  |  8
```

Please share your thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot:

```
df.pivot(None, 'Instruments', 'Volume')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Delivery Month` is already set as an index, the following code will work:

```
df = df.set_index('Instruments',append=True).unstack()
```